# What are options for finding a socket connection and then push data when your connections are spread across multiple hosts

Tags: sockets, websocket, distributed-system, web-development-server

I'm trying to build a web app that operates in real-time via a push model. I've used sockets in the past to achieve this, just not in a distributed service. My question is: Given that the host that receives the updated information (via Amazon
SQS) is not necessarily the host that the necessarily the host that
the web browser has a socket connection open with, How do we find the socket connection and then push the data.

Thanks